# RegEx.Replace issue - Custom URL rewrite

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write my own 301 Redirect. I have 2 strings. One is the old url and other one is new url. The example is below

**Original Url :**

```
procurement-notice-(\d+).html
```

**New url :**

```
/Bids/Details/$1
```

like this, i have plenty of old and new url. I am doing the below to match the Urls which works fine. where the "redirect" is a dictionary contains old and new urls.

```
var matchedURL = redirect.SingleOrDefault(d => Regex.Match(url, d.Key, RegexOptions.Singleline).Success);
```

but now I want to replace the matched one with the new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have matchedURL, where Key - old url regex, and Value - new url replacement pattern.

You can use Regex.Replace method, which accepts 3 string parameters.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class App
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var input = "procurement-notice-1234.html";
    var pattern = @"procurement-notice-(\d+).html";
    var replacement = "/Bids/Details/$1";
    var res = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
    Console.WriteLine(res);
    // will output /Bids/Details/1234
  }
}
```

So in your case, code will probably look like this:

```
var matchedURL = redirect.SingleOrDefault(d => Regex.Match(url, d.Key, RegexOptions.Singleline).Success);
if (matchedURL != null)
{
  var result = Regex.Replace(url, matchedURL.Key, matchedURL.Value);
}
```